# Microsoft Test Manager with C#

Tags: c#, microsoft-test-manager

This is the first time I have used Microsoft Test Manager and I've read that it is possible to use C# to execute test scripts. Unfortunately I was not able to find any tutorials for this anywhere.

I have played around with the application but so far I've only been able to create test cases by manually clicking around and recording it. This can be played back, yes.

I need to know how I can use C# with Microsoft Test Manager. I don't see an editor on the application so does this mean I have to associate the app with a VS12/VS13 solution?

Any help on how to do this would be appreciated.

Comment: What kind of test are you using? Web Performance Test or Coded UI Test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not to associate the Test Manager appication to the Visual Studio, rather TFS does this for you.
You need to create test manually and then associate it with the automated tests using visual studio.
Test created manually in test manager are stored in TFS, you need to query TFS from Visual Studio in order to see the Test Cases created manually, then you need to open the desired test case and click on associated automation tab, there you can browse to the C# test method and associate it with, the manual test case. Status of your test will change from "Not Automated" to "Automated".

You can visit MSDN Documentation, here is a link to [Automate a test case in Microsoft Test Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380741.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is it possible to run an existing unit test (created in Visual Studio) in Microsoft Test Manager? Basically I want to import the test from VS into MTM. If possible, how can I do this?

Comment: If the question asked is sufficed by the answer provided, please approve the answer and post a new question for your query.
it will be beneficial for the other users as well.